# No CComHeapPtr with C++Builder 2010?

Tags: com, atl, c++builder-2010

I'm trying to use [CComHeapPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/80zw33a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) smart pointer with Embarcadero C++Builder 2010, but can't find the definition in any of the supplied headers. And I get this error.

```
[BCC32 Error] E2451 Undefined symbol 'CComHeapPtr'
```

It's not in `atlbase.h` (and `atlalloc.h` seems to be completely missing).

I intended to use this to give exception-safe freeing of the `ItemIDList` returned from `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName`.

Is it present in this version, or does C++Builder just use an incredibly old version of ATL?

And, other than just rolling my own, is there a better alternative?

Comment: Does C++ Builder *at all* has any version of ATL - the library shipped with only non-free versions of MS Visual Studio? No doubt, `CComHeapPtr` is an `ATL` class.

Comment: Yes, it certainly does. ATLBASE.H in particular is there (with an MS copyright), and standard `CComPtr` stuff all works.

Comment: It is perhaps a reduced version, similarly to the one contained in WDK. I don't think `CComHeapPtr` was in ATL all the time, I suppose it was added around Visual Studio 2002-2003 releases and is a relatively "new" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CComHeapPtr` is not available in any version of ATL that has shipped with C++Builder.

C++Builder does support ATL, but older versions of it.  Microsoft has stopped licensing ATL to third-parties, and the latest ATL relies on VC++-specific compiler extensions.  C++Builder XE is the last version that ships with working ATL files.  C++Builder XE2 onwards still support ATL but only if you have a copy of the ATL files from an earlier C++Builder version (XE2 has stub files that have `#error` statements to warn you if you try to use them).  ActiveX is officially supported using Embarcadero's own DAX framework now, which is not ATL-compatible.